# javac showing different version on fedora 23

Tags: fedora, java

I have the following commands from my fedora 23 terminal installed in Oracle VM

```
[root@localhost local]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_60"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
[root@localhost local]# su
[root@localhost local]# update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-14.b27.fc23.x86_64/jre/bin/java
   2           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2
[root@localhost local]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
[root@localhost local]# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_60
[root@localhost local]#
```

I see different version for `javac` and `java` shows the version that I installed. How do I fix this?
I tried running `which java` and `which javac`, the results were `/usr/local/java` and `/usr/local/javac` respectively.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  You initially had it set to openjdk, and your `java -version` confirmed that.  Then you switched it to the second option, and `java -version` confirmed that.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @AndyDalton I was expecting `javac` to show `1.8.0_77` version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java` program and the `javac` alternatives are controlled independently of one another.  Take a look at at what alternative you have set for `javac`.

```
# update-alternatives --config javac

There are 2 programs which provide 'javac'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac
*+ 2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac

# update-alternatives --config java

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   3           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. That's what I was looking for.